# raplace multi line long text in multiple files (notepad++ or other solution)

Tags: replace, notepad++, multiline

I need to replace multi line long text in 5000 files.

I tried with notepad++ but it remove part of my text to search, i think have a limit of characters.

I tried ToolBucket plugin for notepad++ but it can not replace in all files inside a folder, need to open all files in notepad++ before.

I search every solution to do this replace in fast way (notepad++ or other free software).

Text to search:

```
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</ca>
```

Text to replace

```
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</ca>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/) can do that.

Open the folder as a project and go to Edit -> Replace in Files.

When typing your text, you need to type Shift-Enter to type multiple lines. A simple Enter will start the search, Ctrl-Alt-Enter will replace all occurrences.

[image: VSCode Replace in Files]

Comment: I download and tried but do not support multi line find and replace, I search other solutions